# Trying to make aliases that open the last modified file

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, alias

One thing that I frequently do is edit the most recently modified files, so instead of typing "ls -lr" and then "vim lastfile", I thought I would make some shortcuts in my ~/.bash_profile file:

```
alias via="vim `ls -rt | tail -1`"
alias vib="vim `ls -rt | tail -2 | head -1`"
alias vic="vim `ls -rt | tail -3 | head -1`"
alias vid="vim `ls -rt | tail -4 | head -1`"
alias vie="vim `ls -rt | tail -5 | head -1`"
```

The problem is that, weirdly enough, these commands don't work.  They open some file that isn't one of the last, or even a file was deleted from the current directory (I wonder if there's some kind of file cache updating issue in the directory.  This occurs on both my local machine and the cluster I work on).

However, if I type `` vim `ls -rt | tail -1` `` directly, without using the alias, it works every time.

Comment: I'll just leave the standard caveat about [Parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) here.

Comment: Hmm... thanks.  Didn't know all that.

Comment: ...and the advice about [not using backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082). Also, aliases should really go in `.bashrc`, not `.{,bash_}profile`.

Comment: See, this is why I don't like Bash scripting languages.  So many weird exceptions you wouldn't automatically know about.

Comment: *Also, I'm on OS X, which doesn't have a .bashrc and I believe loads .bash_profile on every login session.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you need to quote the backticks in your alias definition. Double quotes (`"`) do not quote command substitution. You will need single quotes (`'`). Use

```
alias via='vim `ls -rt | tail -1`'
```

Though you'd actually want:

```
alias via='vim -- "$(ls -t | head -n 1)"'
```

That is:

- use the modern form of command substitution (`$(...)`) while we are at it.
- quote it to disable the split+glob operator (otherwise it wouldn't work properly if the file name had IFS characters or wildcards (it still doesn't work if it has newline characters)).
- Use `--` to mark the end of options for `vim` (otherwise, it wouldn't work for filenames starting with `-` or `+`).
- Use `ls -t | head` instead of `ls -rt | tail` to get the result sooner.

Do not use

```
alias via="vim `ls -rt | tail -1`"
```

If you do that the command substitution happens when you define the alias, not when you run it. Try typing `alias via` to see that the output is not actually `` alias via='vim `ls -rt | tail -1`' `` but rather `alias via='vim <prematurely expanded output>'`.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` (also pre-installed on OS/X) and assuming you're using the completion system (`compinit` and co), <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> becomes a completer that expands to the newest file.

So:

```
vi Ctrl+Xm
```

Would make you edit the newest file (you also get a chance to see which it before you press <kbd>Return</kbd>).

```
vi Alt+2Ctrl+Xm
```

For the second-newest file.

```
vi *.cCtrl+Xm
```

for the newest `c` file.

```
vi *(.)Ctrl+Xm
```

for the newest *regular* file (not directory, nor fifo/device...), and so on.

You also define your alias as:

```
alias via='vim -- *(.om[1])'
```

To edit the newest (non-hidden) regular file in the current directory without the problems involved with parsing the output of `ls`.

With `bash` and assuming the GNU implementation of `find` and `sort`, you could achieve the same with a function like:

```
via() {
  local file
  IFS=/ read -rd '' file file < <(
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f  ! -name '.*' -printf '%T@/%f\0' |
    sort -rzn
  ) && vim -- "$file"
}
```

Which you could parameterize to be able to specify the second, third... newest file with (assuming GNU Bash 4.4 or newer and GNU coreutils 8.25 or newer):

```
via() {
  local files
  readarray -d '' -t files < <(
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f  ! -name '.*' -printf '%T@/%f\0' |
    sort -rzn | cut -zd / -f 2
  ) && ((${#files[@]} >= ${1-1} )) && vim -- "${files[${1-1}-1]}"
}
```

To use as:

```
via 3
```

for instance to edit the third newest file.